# Jqgrid row selected on clicking on disabled prev and next pager

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid, where i face an odd problem

I have some ten records in the grid, so i have the pager NEXT and PREVIOUS button disabled. Now on clicking on the disabled NEXT and PREVIOUS buttons and after click on the records one by one, after each time clicking on the next and previous button, multiple rows in the gird are getting selected, Which should not happen

How to avoid this behaviour, Does any one already resolved this issues

Please let me know it.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: This issue is there in the demo itself, here is the demo link. http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/selection/selectedrow_client/default.php. Just click on the disabled prev or next first and click on any of the rows, a new row will be selected. if you try this you can see this issue

Comment: But with out clicking on the prev or next disable buttons, you can able to select one rows only at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right! It'a a bug in jqGrid. **Disabled** buttons can be clicked at least in IE browser. Later processing of such click in jqGrid follow setting of `selrow` to `null`. If the next row will be selected, *after* previous clicking on disabled pager button, jqGrid removes `ui-state-highlight` class only from the line having id `selrow`. Because the parameter `selrow` have now `null` value one will have more as one selected rows in case of usage default `multiselect: false` option.

One can fix the bug by adding the line

```js
if ($(this).hasClass("ui-state-disabled")) { return false; }
```

as the first line of the click event handler registered on pager buttons (after [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.4/js/grid.base.js#L2107) which has the number 2107 in `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` of version 4.5.4).

I posted [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/more-as-one-rows-could-be-selected-with-multiselect-false-if-disabled-pager-button-will-be-clicked-before/#p29883) the corresponding bug report to trirand.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I have already raised a request, but not to Tony. For the mean time i have done some work around in fixing this issue.

Comment: @BabuArumugam: You are welcome! Do you tried to implement the changes which I suggested? It fix the problem.

Comment: Sry Oleg i did not come back to see the post, it is working. Btw Did you pushed the code fix for this bug. If it is done then i can use it directly instead of adding a hack.

Comment: @BabuArumugam: The bug fix which I posted as a part of [the pull request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/more-as-one-rows-could-be-selected-with-multiselect-false-if-disabled-pager-button-will-be-clicked-before/#p29883) is merged to the main code of jqGrid. See [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L2172-L2175) the lines in the current version of jqGrid.

Comment: Thank you. Today i downloaded the latest 4.5.4 version. In that version the fix was not available.

Comment: @BabuArumugam: trirand (Tony) don't published new release since a long time. I posted the bug report as [the pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/551) at 3 Dez 2013 **after** publishing of jqGrid 4.5.4. You can read in my answer on your question which lines of **`jquery.jqGrid.src.js of version 4.5.4`** need be changed. So I answered you after publishing 4.5.4 version. I'm waiting that Tony will publish it in the next days (see [the answer](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/date-having-wrong-parsed-with-srcformat-iso8601long/#p30206) on one from my bug reports).

Comment: Thanks Oleg for your prompt reply. I think for now i use the fix manually in my code. Once released i will take update it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need an always-single-selected grid. This may help:

```
    beforeSelectRow: function(id){
        $('#grid tr.ui-state-highlight').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
        $('#grid tr#' + id).addClass('ui-state-highlight'); 
    },
```